# Comment appears in the inbox, but not in the post

Tags: support, comments

I see a comment appear in my inbox, as:

[image]

But I don't see it in the concerned post. What happened to it?

Answer (score 5):

The user which wrote the comment deleted it again. In this cases you sometimes still get a notification. Don't worry about it.